# What would be the maximum critical magnetic field of superconducting hydrogen?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity

Say you have a superconductor made of metallic hydrogen. What would the be the maximum critical magnetic field?

I know that the new superconducting magnets such as YBCO can reach field strengths of up to 30 Tesla but given the extraordinary properties of metallic hydrogen I wonder what might be possible here.